# Test Driven Development in iOS... to TDD or not to TDD

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tdd, ios6

I'm starting to program in iOS and I've been wondering if I should do Test Driven Development.

I come from a rails background, where TDD is a way of life for many and where the TDD-tools are great.

How are the views on TDD in iOS?

Comment: TDD practices are much more diverse in iOS development ranging from non-existent to more obsessive TDD.  I'd say that at least selective unit testing of the model layer and important services is the norm.  The tools are improving.  OCUnit had a lot of problems with Xcode 4 early-on.  Now much better.  OCMock is a good mocking framework, though I wish that a more complete integrated test suite was available in Xcode.

Comment: I just haven't seen any examples of people doing test-first development in iOS. Is it even possible? Is it a good idea? Do you have any resources for learning it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do you have any resources for learning it?

- [Test-driven Development in iOS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774183) - good book by a respected author.  Nice intro to the tools.
- [Making fun of things with OCMock](http://alexvollmer.com/posts/2010/06/28/making-fun-of-things-with-ocmock/) - a tutorial on OCMock, the mocking framework most Cocoa devs use
- [Unit testing tutorial/OCUnit](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3716/unit-testing-in-xcode-4-quick-start-guide) - one of several OCUnit tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I TDD my iOS work, both professionally and individually. I have apps in the store with 98% coverage. One starting point is my blog post [Xcode TDD 101 with the Bowling Game Kata.](https://qualitycoding.org/xcode-tdd/)

The tools I use are:

- OCUnit (a.k.a. SenTestingKit) built in to Xcode
- [OCHamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/OCHamcrest) for most assertions
- [OCMockito](https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito) for most mocks
- [lcov](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php) to see what coverage holes I may have inadvertently introduced

Comment: Just for an update on how to do Unit Testing on Xcode 5 using XCTest framework : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cpEIik-FZM